# Python add leading zeroes using str.format

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, string-formatting

Can you display an integer value with leading zeroes using the [`str.format`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) function?

**Example input:**

```
"{0:some_format_specifying_width_3}".format(1)
"{0:some_format_specifying_width_3}".format(10)
"{0:some_format_specifying_width_3}".format(100)
```

**Desired output:**

```
"001"
"010"
"100"
```

I know that both `zfill` and `%`-based formatting (e.g. `'%03d' % 5`) can accomplish this. However, I would like a solution that uses `str.format` in order to keep my code clean and consistent (I'm also formatting the string with datetime attributes) and also to expand my knowledge of the [Format Specification Mini-Language](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language).

Comment: Are `max_width`, `a`, `b`, and `c` variable names or is your input a string?

Comment: Those are just some example variable names.  `max_width` was used for the example to indicate how many leading zeroes would be necessary for the example values. In my actual code the input to format includes a datetime object and some ints that I would like to format with leading zeroes.

Comment: so you want a 1-liner with `format` or a function that uses nothing but raw python would suffice?

Comment: Yes I am asking if it is possible (and how) to do it with just `format`.

Answer (score 204, accepted):

```
>>> "{0:0>3}".format(1)
'001'
>>> "{0:0>3}".format(10)
'010'
>>> "{0:0>3}".format(100)
'100'
```

Explanation:

```
{0 : 0 > 3}
 │   │ │ │
 │   │ │ └─ Width of 3
 │   │ └─ Align Right
 │   └─ Fill with '0'
 └─ Element index
```

Comment: Ah, I think my examples were interpreted a bit too literally.  I simply want a format that makes `"{0:some_format_specifying_width_four}".format(10)` produce `"0010"`.

Comment: I updated my original examples to provide more clarity

Answer (score 30):

Derived from [Format examples, Nesting examples](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-examples) in the Python docs:

```
>>> '{0:0{width}}'.format(5, width=3)
'005'
```

Comment: Excellent! I'm accepting @F.J's answer as I prefer not specifying another variable for width, though this answer does seem very pythonic in its explicitness!

Comment: That will happen when you edit the question after it's been answered. I'm glad we could help you clarify your intention.