# Most pythonic way to pad a float left of the decimal point

Tags: python, python-2.7

What I'm trying to accomplish

```
-12.345 -> -012.345
```

Where left of decimal can be -999->999 (for my specific need) and n-amount of decimal digits

I came up with two methods to do this:

```
def pad(num, pad):
    pad = pow(10,pad)
    if num > 0:
        return "%s" %  str(num + pad)[1:]
    else:
        return "-%s" % str(num - pad)[2:]

def pad(num, pad):
    import math
    mag  = 1 + int(math.log10(abs(num)))
    sz   = len(str(num))
    return str(num).zfill(pad+sz-mag)
```

but this seems rather obtuse for being python. I saw a previous similar question but didn't like the answer ...

```
>>> "%06.2f"%3.3
'003.30'
```

because it assumes you already know where your decimal point is and how many decimal digits you have.

This seems like a common situation, so is there an existing better/cleaner/single fncall, way to go about this in python 2.7?

Comment: I believe [```str.format()```](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatspec) is what you want

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17118071/python-add-leading-zeroes-using-str-format looks like it works nicely with ints but not floats since my width is variable depending on the amount of decimal digits, so from what I can tell, I'd still need to count the number of decimal digits I have :\

Comment: @pyInTheSky: what do you mean *amount of decimal digits*? Floats are *approximations*, you invariably end up rounding *anyway*. `-12.345` is not *exactly* `-12.345` either, for example. `format(-12.345, '.53f')` > `'-12.34500000000000063948846218409016728401184082031250000'`.

Comment: So you want a fixed width of 3 on the left and variable width on the right?

Comment: @user2357112 that is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is pythonic. It just pad integer and concat the decimal.

```
def pad(x, p):
    return ('%0'+str(p+(x<0 and 1 or 0))+'d%s') % (x,str(x-int(x))[x<0 and 2 or 1:])
```

tests

```
pad(-3,3) -> -003
pad(3,3) -> 003
pad(-3.3,3) -> -003.3
pad(3.3,3) -> 003.3
```

Comment: A bummer that there doesn't seem to be a pretty built in way, but b.a. for some crazy splicing logic. I did not know that that could be done.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have found a corner case.  It's easy to specify digits to the left and to the right of the decimal place; it's also easy to specify total number of digits; it's not very easy to specify digits to the left and leave digits to the right completely unspecified.

I suggest that the cleanest thing to do is to just take the integer portion of the float and format that, then take the fraction and format that (not specifying a length).

Here's a tested function that does what you asked for, and also works correctly for negative numbers.

```
import math

def float_lformat(f, width):
    neg = f < 0.0
    fraction, n = math.modf(abs(f)) # get fraction and integer parts of f
    if neg and width > 0:
        width -= 1
    s = "%0*d" % (width, n) + str(fraction)[1:]
    if neg:
        s = '-' + s
    return s
```

Comment: Yeah, I'm taking a NMEA lat. value that's been converted from str to float (losing it's leading 0 for lats < 100) and then formatting it back later on, so not the most common way to display numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed vs. dynamic fractions:

```
>>> "{:08}".format(-12.345)
'-012.345'

>>> a,b=str(x).split('.');a=int(a);"{}{:03}.{}".format('-' if a<0 else"",abs(a),b)
'-012.345'
```

Cleaned up:

```
def pad(x):
    a, b = str(x).split('.')
    a = int(a)
    return '{}{:03}.{}'.format('-' if a < 0 else ' ', abs(a), b)

for x in [12.0, 12.345, -12.345, -12.3456]:
    print('{:>8} -> {}'.format(x, pad(x)))
```

Output:

```
    12.0 ->  012.0
  12.345 ->  012.345
 -12.345 -> -012.345
-12.3456 -> -012.3456
```