# Get the string in 2 digit format with leading zeros in python

Tags: python

I have a requirement to add 2 string which are in mac format as hex which has 9 octets. As part of that I have achieved almost, but one final thing pending is to get the value in 2 digit format.

```
string1= "aa.aa.aa.aa.aa.aa.aa.aa.ff"
string2= "00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.01"
```

when I add these 2 the out put I get is `aa.aa.aa.aa.aa.aa.aa.ab.0` but I want value to be `aa.aa.aa.aa.aa.aa.aa.ab.00` . (2 zeros).

I tried using

```
temp = '%02d' % string3
```

but I got error

```
TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not str
```

as I am trying to do that with string.

Comment: Where b comes from?'

Comment: Have you tried converting that string part to int?

Comment: How are you adding the two strings?

Comment: Avinash I am adding two string in Hex format so ff+1 will be 1 00 with 1 carry backwards so here aa.ff becomes ab.00

Answer (score 1):

You can split the string, pad each part with leading zeros and join it again:

```
s = "aa.aa.aa.aa.aa.aa.aa.ab.0"
print '.'.join(["{0:0>2}".format(w) for w in s.split('.')])
```

Output:

```
aa.aa.aa.aa.aa.aa.aa.ab.00
```

(The padding is based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17118161/3419103).)

---

Even shorter version based on [`map`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map):

```
print '.'.join(map("{0:0>2}".format, s.split('.')))
```

Comment: Thank you so much Falko. It worked. Which one is better among both methods? Padding or map based?

Comment: The `format` function does the padding. So the difference is using a [list comprehension](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk) or the `map` function. In my point of view it doesn't really matter which one to use here. With `map` you save a temporary variable, which might improve readability.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of fixing the resulting `string3`, you can improve the way you create it. If you convert the summands to integers, add them and convert the result back to a hex representation, you don't have to worry about missing zeros:

```
a = "aa.aa.aa.aa.aa.aa.aa.aa.ff"
b = "00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.01"
c = hex(int(a.replace('.', ''), 16) + int(b.replace('.', ''), 16))[2:-1]
print '.'.join(i+j for i,j in zip(c[::2], c[1::2]))
```

Output:

```
aa.aa.aa.aa.aa.aa.aa.ab.00
```

References:

- Converting hex to int: https://stackoverflow.com/a/209550/3419103
- Converting int to hex: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2269836/3419103
- Inserting a `.` every two characters: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3258596/3419103

Comment: This is awesome. I have around 15 lines of code to do this. but you made in just 3 lines...Genius. Thanks again.