# Python: Syntax error:Invalid token

Tags: python, python-3.x

I just started learning pyhton and while working with comparison operators,i got this error when i executed the following code with '==' operator,

```
40 == 0040.0
```

resulted into True,from the interpreter,and also

```
40 == 40.0
```

resulted in True

but when i executed the below code,

```
40 == 0040
```

it throwed an error as,

> File "stdin", line 1
>
> 40 == 0040
>
> SyntaxError: invalid token

pointing invalid token to trailing zero.

Please help me to understand what is happening.Thank you in advance.

Comment: 0040 as 000040 already treated as hexadecimal and if you int(0040)  or int(000040) you'll get 32

Comment: @dmitryro Did you mean octal?

Comment: @dmitryro 0040 is a SyntaxError, not a hexadecimal or octal number (the latter should have `0o` instead of `00`. Spot the difference.)

Comment: hi dmitryro: before converting to int ,it has to be converted to decimal right?if iam not wrong

Comment: @SubSea for your reference https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#integer-literals

Comment: yes it is a decimal number..

Comment: yes,without trailing dot it will not assume this

Comment: Be careful about calling numbers "decimal" in Python: that is quite a [different module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) altogether.

Comment: I think. "First zero makes number octal.". Refer to this question once if you get help from that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/336181/python-invalid-token

Comment: Hi Gunjan: if it leads to octal ,then it should result into False ..right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python 3 doesn't allow numbers with leading zeroes to prevent confusion with octal values. If you must have leading zeroes, use `format()`.

It's clearer in Python 2 where `40 == 0040` evaluates to `False`.

EDIT: Example taken from link in comment:

`>>> "{0:0>3}".format(1)
'001'`

Further explanation:

`{0 : 0 > 3}
 │   │ │ │
 │   │ │ └─ Width of 3
 │   │ └─ Align Right
 │   └─ Fill with '0'
 └─ Element index`

Comment: Hi meatspace,can u once show me how can i use format()?

Comment: This explains it concisely: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17118071/python-add-leading-zeroes-using-str-format

Answer (score 1):

For floating point numbers, leading zeros are accepted, and them simply ignored (since they don't contribute anything but readability).
Thus, `0040.0` is the floating point number `40.0`.

For integer numbers, the zero at the start of a number takes on a different meaning: depending on the next character, it indicates the rest of the number should be interpreted as an octal (`o` or `O`), hexadecimal (`x` or `X`) or binary number (`b` or `B`).
If another character follows the first `0`, it will be a `SyntaxError`. That is what you're seeing for `0040`: there is no hint that it should be a floating point number (no 'e', 'd' or a decimal point, '.'), nor is the second zero a prefix for an different integer base.

The exact definitions for floating point and integer numbers are given in the [lexical analysis of the Python reference](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#integer-literals).

---

The results of your comparisons evaluating to `True` is a different beast, and just indicates that floating point 40 happens to be an exact representation, equal to integer 40.

(For how and why on integers and floats, see for example the SO question that ask about [the first integer that can't be represented by a float](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3793838/which-is-the-first-integer-that-an-ieee-754-float-is-incapable-of-representing-e).)