# Python - Printing numbers with spacing format

Tags: python, string, list, format, number-formatting

Let's say I have an array of numbers where

```
list = [(4, 3, 7, 23),(17, 4021, 4, 92)]
```

and I want to print the numbers out in such a way so that the output looks somewhat like this:

```
[   4  |   3  |   7  |  23  ] 
[  17  | 4021 |   4  |  92  ]
```

Where the numbers are as centered as possible and that there is enough space in between the "|" to allow a 4 digit number with two spaces on either side.

How would I do this?

Thank you.

Comment: Calling your variable `list` might not be a good thing

Answer (score 4):

[str.center](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.center) can make things easier.

```
for i in list:
    print '[ ' + ' | '.join([str(j).center(4) for j in i]) + ' ]'
```

Output:

```
[  4   |  3   |  7   |  23  ]
[  17  | 4021 |  4   |  92  ]
```

In case you need an alternative solution, you can use [str.format](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-examples):

```
for i in list:
    print '[ ' + ' | '.join(["{:^4}".format(j) for j in i]) + ' ]'
```

Output:

```
[  4   |  3   |  7   |  23  ]
[  17  | 4021 |  4   |  92  ]
```

Comment: Instead of hard coding _4,_ you may want to do:
`_list = [(4, 3, 7, 23),(17, 4021, 4, 92)] ;
lst = [len(str(x)) for i in _list for x in i] ;
_width = max(lst) ;`

Answer (score 3):

You can also use third-parties like [`PrettyTable`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PrettyTable) or [`texttable`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi?name=texttable&%3Aaction=display). Example using `texttable`:

```
import texttable

l = [(4, 3, 7, 23),(17, 4021, 4, 92)]

table = texttable.Texttable()
# table.set_chars(["", "|", "", ""])
table.add_rows(l)

print(table.draw())
```

Would produce:

```
+----+------+---+----+
| 4  |  3   | 7 | 23 |
+====+======+===+====+
| 17 | 4021 | 4 | 92 |
+----+------+---+----+
```

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
list = [[4, 3, 7, 23],[17, 4021, 4, 92]]

for sublist in list:
    output = "["
    for index, x in enumerate(sublist):
        output +='{:^6}'.format(x) 
        if index != len(sublist)-1:
            output += '|'  
    output +=']'
    print output
```

Output:

```
[  4   |  3   |  7   |  23  ]
[  17  | 4021 |  4   |  92  ]
```

Answer (score 0):

This works - for details refer to [Correct way to format integers with fixed length and space padding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45731862/correct-way-to-format-integers-with-fixed-length-and-space-padding) and  [Python add leading zeroes using str.format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17118071/python-add-leading-zeroes-using-str-format)

```
list = [(4, 3, 7, 23),(17, 4021, 4, 92)]
for sublist in list:
    print('[ ', end =" ")
    for val in sublist:
        print("{:4d}".format(val) + ' | ' , end =" ")
    print('] ')
```

Sample output

```
[     4 |     3 |     7 |    23 |  ] 
[    17 |  4021 |     4 |    92 |  ]
```